# How to pick file from external storage using file picker in Android

Tags: android, file, android-external-storage

I am having a problem with selecting image file from external storage using file picker in Android. This question is the consequence of this question - [No such file or diectory error in image file upload using Retrofit in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063289/no-such-file-or-diectory-error-in-image-file-upload-using-retrofit-in-android?noredirect=1#comment65475927_39063289). What my problem is opening and reading file from external storage on activity result. I want to convert result URI into File.

I read a pdf file from download folder on activity result

```
Uri bookUri = data.getData();
                if(bookUri!=null)
                {
                    String filePath = bookUri.toString();//bookUri.toString()
                    String mime = app.getMimeType(filePath);
                    if(mime!=null && !mime.isEmpty() && (mime.toLowerCase()=="application/pdf" || mime.toLowerCase()=="application/txt" || mime.toLowerCase()=="application/text"))
                    {
                        bookFile = new File(bookUri.getPath());
                        ivBookFile.setImageResource(R.drawable.book_selected);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Unable to process file you have chosen.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
```

As you can see I used new File(bookUri.getPath()); to convert into File. The above code works well. It is working. The problem is now I am trying to open an image file in DCIM/Camera folder on activity result.

This is the code I used

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                if(selectedImageUri!=null)
                {
                    try{
                        bmpCoverImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
                        imageFile = new File(selectedImageUri.getPath());
                        if(bmpCoverImage!=null)
                        {
                            ivCoverImage.setImageBitmap(bmpCoverImage);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"An error occurred with the file selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
```

As you can see I used new File(selectedImageUri.getPath()); like I did in reading pdf file. This time the code is not working. When I do operation with the file like in previous question, it gives me error.

I used this way also

```
imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),selectedImageUri.getPath());
```

I got the same error. How can I open the image file correctly from external storage? How can I convert the chosen file URI from external storage into File?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am having a problem with selecting image file from external storage using file picker in Android

If you are referring to the code that you are using in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063289/no-such-file-or-diectory-error-in-image-file-upload-using-retrofit-in-android?noredirect=1#comment65475927_39063289), you are not "using file picker". You are using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, which has never been a "file picker", nor will it ever be a "file picker".

> I want to convert result URI into File.

Usually, that is not necessary. But, if that is what you want to do:

- use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content represented by the `Uri`
- create a `FileOutputStream` on your desired file
- use Java I/O to copy the bytes from the `InputStream` into the `FileOutputStream`

> The above code works well. It is working.

It works for the small number of devices that you tested, for the specific activities that the user chose to handle the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` request. It will not work on most Android devices, and it will not work in most circumstances. The only time that code will work is if the `Uri` has a `file` scheme. Most of the time, it will not. Instead, it will have a `content` scheme, representing content supplied by a `ContentProvider`.

> Please how can I open the image file correctly from external storage?

If you wish to continue using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, please understand that **this has nothing to do with external storage** specifically. You are not getting a file, on external storage or elsewhere. You are getting a `Uri`. This is akin to a URL, such as the URL for this Web page. Just as a URL does not necessarily point to a file on your hard drive, a `Uri` does not necessarily point to a file on the filesystem. Use a `ContentResolver` and `DocumentFile` to work with the `Uri` and the content that it identifies.

If you want to *always* get files on external storage (and nowhere else), then use [an actual file picker library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/35).

Comment: Thank u so much. I will try on it. Now I got what is wrong with me and u clearly pointed me out. Now I learned a good lesson from u.

Comment: I already tried on it. I installed a file picker. It works perfect. Thank so much.